# Database crashed after IO Wait spiked

Tags: magento-1.9, database

On a magento 1.9 site (latest version), the database crashed.  Looking at the server stats, the IO Wait spiked rapidly, and then it crashed.

I have some stuff that will upload photos.  Anybody ever heard of anything like this?

Comment: John, RAM always helps.  Even though you are running, to improve performance, - Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf-ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the database memory was exhausted.  Just needed to add more RAM to the server